# Accessing Appfog MongoDB service

Tags: mongodb, connection, appfog

How can I acces MongoDB service running on Appfog from my local? I want to use it with gui application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using an AppFog MongoDB add-on and that the GUI tool you want to use is running locally on your machine, is that correct?

It's not clear to me what GUI application you're trying to use, but chances are it accepts a MongoDB URI of the form "mongodb://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[dbname]" You can use this info to connect through the db shell, too. Or if your tool doesn't take a URI, you can cut&paste specific values from the URI according to the format.

If you are using an AppFog MongoDB addon, then you can get the value for your URI from the Env Variables section of your app page at the AppFog portal. You can also get that value in your code, per something like https://docs.appfog.com/add-ons/mongolab.

You should also keep in mind that MongoDB services often have their own management UI that you can use. If you go to the Addons section of your application page on AppFog, scroll to your provider and click "Manage" you can access their tools as well.

Good luck, and let me know if I have misunderstood your question.

Sincerely,
Eric